# www subdomain not working on mobile

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system

I have a website with A records setup for the root domain and for the www subdomain.

My nginx vhost:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.example.com;
        return       301 http://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {

        server_name example.com;

        ...
}
```

When I visit the `www` site I expect to be redirected to the root domain - however, the `www` remains in the URL, no redirect occurs. The site loads as expected at the root domain and the `www` subdomain, but I'm looking for it to redirect.

Comment: Maybe my translation filter is failing me but when you’re trying to set up a redirect and then conclude *“This works on desktop, although it does not redirect“* it simply does NOT work. - Also please note that 301 is a **permanent redirect** and (even when it is incorrect) it will be cached by browsers so keep that in mind. if you’re doing multiple tests please use new incognito/anonymous windows/tabs for each test. Check your web server logs to see if the 301 is sent, and if a redirected request arrives for the correct url or another

Comment: Also note [Chrome 69 breaks URLs](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/09/07/google_kills_www/) by chopping off the "unimportant" bits, like "www." or "m.".

Comment: Apologies @HBruijn - I meant the page loads, but the redirect does not occur. Both these comments were valid - my phone was indeed caching, the cache is a lot stickier than I had thought. I removed the nginx default site and restarted and the redirect now happens as expected. Many thanks.